# dyld: Symbol not found: OAuthSwift Xcode 8.1 CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, cocoapods, xcode8

I know why this is happening but not sure how to fix this.

I am using two CocoaPods that both come bundled with `OAuthSwift`. When I authenticate a service, it can't find the reference to the `OAuthSwift` dependency and I get the following error:

> dyld: Symbol not found: __TIFC10OAuthSwift16OAuthSwiftClient7requestFTSS6methodOCS_21OAuthSwiftHTTPRequest6Method10parametersGVs10DictionarySSP__7headersGSqGS3_SSSS__4bodyGSqV10Foundation4Data_20checkTokenExpirationSb7successGSqFTS5_CSo15HTTPURLResponse_T__7failureGSqFOS_15OAuthSwiftErrorT___GSqPS_23OAuthSwiftRequestHandle__A3_
>
> Referenced from:
>   /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E0E-6B8F0CE25EFD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9853-D2AF097FF8A2/MyApp.app/Frameworks/PodSDK.framework/PodSDK
>
> Expected in:
>   /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E0E-6B8F0CE25EFD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9853-D2AF097FF8A2/MyApp.app/Frameworks/OAuthSwift.framework/OAuthSwift